# dynamically change function name in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('a').live('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    infowindow2.open(map, marker2); // I need instead of 2 to print the value of variable id
});
```

How can I dynamically change the number 2 to variable ID ?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
$('a').live('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    infowindow2.open(map, eval('marker' + id)); 
});
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FVaNf/)**

**Notes:**

- `eval` is deprecated, **You should look for a better design.**
- so as `live`... You should use `on` instead.

Answer (score 10):

Don't use `eval`, use a hash:

```
var markers = {
    "key1": function(){},
    "key2": function(){},
    "key3": function(){}
};

$('a').live('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = this.id; //Use this.id instead of attr
    infowindow2.open(map, markers[id]);
});
```

Comment: lol, Dennis, i was 7 seconds faster than you )) _identical answers_

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using `eval`, - better change you data structures:

```
var  markers = {
    '1': function () { doStuff(); },
    '2': function () { doOtherStuff(); },
}
$('a').live('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    infowindow2.open(map, markers[id]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

#### EVAL should always be the last option

In order use dynamic name in a function names you can windows object.

Here is an Example:

```
var id = '2';
function map2() {
    alert('me called');
}
window["map"+id]();
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/qvJzv/)

Your Usage would be something like this

```
$('a').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    infowindow2.open(map, window['map'+id]()); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to write a new function with a switch. I can't recommend using eval.